# Load CSS into React Component not working, using webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

so I started my app and Im trying to use CSS for my React Components, I included my css rules in the `webpack` file:

This is the file structure:
[image]

The error that I get is :

```
ERROR in ./client/src/related_items/styles/Card.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .Card-Component {
|   border: 1px solid black;
| }
 @ ./client/src/related_items/Card.jsx 2:0-27
 @ ./client/src/related_items/App.jsx 2:0-26 8:163-167
 @ ./client/src/App.jsx 26:0-51 78:43-55
 @ ./client/src/index.js 3:0-28 4:50-53

webpack 5.52.0 compiled with 1 error in 13 ms
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

const SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'src');
const OUT_DIR = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'dist');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.join(SRC_DIR, 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: OUT_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
};
```

Im simply trying to use CSS in a component:

Card Component

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/Card.css';

const Card = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Card-Component">
      <h1>This is a Card</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card;
```

This is my CSS:

```
.Card-Component {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "front-end-capstone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "react-dev": "webpack -w",
    "server-dev": "nodemon server/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.1.1",
    "mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.39.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.52.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the structure of the files? You might be importing the CSS wrongly

Comment: @TomasMota I included the file structure at the top

Comment: @TomasMota Problem fixed, I killed my webpack and re-run it in watch mode, for some reason, it was not registering the changes

Comment: I'm glad it worked. But if you are inside the Card.jsx and want to access the Card.css which is inside the styles you need to add an extra . in the source


``` ../styles/card.css

Answer (score 0):

Just killed webpack and re run it again, thought that having in in watch mode would do it